# Paging postback in Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, refresh, postback

Is there any way to prevent reloading of whole website while changing page in Listview? I mean that when I click on next page button it's reloading whole website once more... Can I go to the next page in listview without refreshing everything?

Thanks in advance!

```
    <div class="imageset">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/oferta.aspx?cat=" + Request.QueryString["cat"] + "&id={0}") %>' Width="180px" Height="120px" CssClass="imagebtn" CommandName="Choose" />
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/oferta.aspx?cat=" + Request.QueryString["cat"] + "&id={0}") %>' Width="180px" Height="120px" CssClass="imagebtn" CommandName="Choose" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [P_Produkty] WHERE ([kategoria] = @kategoria)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="kategoria" QueryStringField="cat" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div class="bottombtn">
        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" runat="server" PagedControlID="Listview1" PageSize="3">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Image" FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" NextPageImageUrl="~/images/arrowbtndown.png" NextPageText="" PreviousPageText="" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ButtonCssClass="bottombtn" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
    </div>
```

Comment: use ajax programming. If you want to reload only some contents of web page. Please post code to be specific. Thanks

Comment: Just added the asp code.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `<asp:ListView>` in a `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and Add the `PageIndexChanged` event of ListView as `aSyncPostBackTrigger` of UpdatePanel.
Something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListView `ID="listview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
//columns
</asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
<aSyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="listview1" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
</UpdatePanel>`
```